# Remove Timer Permanently On Button Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, timer

I have a popup which automatically loads when the page is loaded, it also has a timer on the close button whose time on it varies depending on how many times the popup was viewed by the user. It also has a 'Print' button and the popup can be called back up if you press the key 'g'.

My focus is on the 'Print' button. Currently when I click the 'Print' button it adds the following bit of code:

```
$("#timer").remove();
clearInterval(setMsg);
```

However if you were to reload the page the timer would reappear as if the button hadn't been clicked at all, it would be either `5`, `15`, `30`, `45` or `60` seconds depending on how many times you had previously viewed the page. I would like the timer to permanently be removed after the 'Print' button has been clicked. This could probably be achieved by `localStorage` or a cookie but I am not experienced in those categories.

Please note the timer does not appear to work in the snippet or the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ChippeRock/wt1gb9of/4/) as I believe several of the functions are prevented from working such as `document.write`. If you want the code to work copy it into an HTML file and run it in your browser. My code is below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.charCode === 65 || 103) {
      $('#PopUp').css("visibility", "visible");
      $('#PopUp').css("opacity", 1);
    }
  });
  
  $(function() {
    $('#PopUp').css("visibility", "visible");
    $('#PopUp').css("opacity", 1);
  });

  $(".close").click(function() {
    $('#PopUp').css("visibility", "hidden");
    $('#PopUp').css("opacity", 0);
  });
});

// initialization
var counter = 60;
var timesVisited = 0;
var cookieExpirationDays = 7; // don't expire cookies for a week
// test to see if localstorage/sessionStorage is available (localStorage has no expiration date)

if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
  counter = 60;
  timesVisited = localStorage.getItem("timesVisited");
  // first time
  if ((timesVisited == 0) || (timesVisited < 1)) {
    timesVisited = 1;
    localStorage.setItem("timesVisited", timesVisited);
    counter = 60;
  }
  // second time
  else if ((timesVisited >= 1) && (timesVisited <= 3)) {
    timesVisited++;
    localStorage.setItem("timesVisited", timesVisited);
    counter = 45;
  }
  // third time
  else if ((timesVisited >= 4) && (timesVisited <= 8)) {
    timesVisited++;
    localStorage.setItem("timesVisited", timesVisited);
    counter = 30;
  }
  // fourth time
  else if ((timesVisited >= 9) && (timesVisited <= 13)) {
    timesVisited++;
    localStorage.setItem("timesVisited", timesVisited);
    counter = 15;
  }
  // fifth time
  else if (timesVisited >= 14) {
    timesVisited++;
    localStorage.setItem("timesVisited", timesVisited);
    counter = 5;
  }
}
// No localstorage/sessionStorage. Use cookies 
else {
  timesVisited = getCookie("timesVisited");
  console.log(timesVisited);
  // first time
  if ((timesVisited == "") || (timesVisited < 1)) {
    timesVisited = 1;
    setCookie("timesVisited", timesVisited, cookieExpirationDays);
    counter = 60;
  }
  // second time
  else if ((timesVisited >= 1) && (timesVisited <= 3)) {
    timesVisited++;
    setCookie("timesVisited", timesVisited, cookieExpirationDays);
    counter = 45;
  }
  // third time
  else if ((timesVisited >= 4) && (timesVisited <= 8)) {
    timesVisited++;
    setCookie("timesVisited", timesVisited, cookieExpirationDays);
    counter = 30;
  }
  // fourth time
  else if ((timesVisited >= 9) && (timesVisited <= 13)) {
    timesVisited++;
    setCookie("timesVisited", timesVisited, cookieExpirationDays);
    counter = 15;
  }
  // fifth time
  else if (timesVisited >= 14) {
    timesVisited++;
    setCookie("timesVisited", timesVisited, cookieExpirationDays);
    counter = 5;
  }
}
var setMsg = setInterval(function() {
  counter--;
  if (counter >= 60 && counter >= 70) {
    $("#close-message").html("1:" + (counter - 60));
  } else if (counter >= 60 && counter < 70) {
    $("#close-message").html("1:0" + (counter - 60));
  } else if (counter >= 10) {
    $("#close-message").html("0:" + counter);
  } else if (counter > 0) {
    $("#close-message").html("0:0" + counter);
  } else {
    $(".close").click(function() {
      $('#PopUp').css("visibility", "hidden");
      $('#PopUp').css("opacity", 0);
    });
    $("#timer").remove();
    clearInterval(setMsg);
  }
}, 1000);
});

        function printDiv()
        {
            var content = document.getElementById('content').innerHTML;
            var win = window.open();
            win.document.write(content);
            win.print(); // JavaScript Print Function
            win.close(); //It will close window after Print.
        $( ".close" ).click(function() {
          $('#PopUp').css("visibility", "hidden"); 
          $('#PopUp').css("opacity", 0);
        });
        $("#timer").remove();
         clearInterval(setMsg);s
        }
```

```css
.t {
  -webkit-transform-origin: top left;
  -moz-transform-origin: top left;
  -o-transform-origin: top left;
  -ms-transform-origin: top left;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.25);
  -moz-transform: scale(0.25);
  -o-transform: scale(0.25);
  -ms-transform: scale(0.25);
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  white-space: pre;
  overflow: visible;
}

#t1_1 {
  left: 256px;
  top: 35px;
  letter-spacing: 0.1px;
}

#t2_1 {
  left: 334px;
  top: 87px;
  word-spacing: -0.1px;
}

#t3_1 {
  left: 210px;
  top: 123px;
}

#t4_1 {
  left: 238px;
  top: 123px;
  word-spacing: -0.3px;
}

#t5_1 {
  left: 210px;
  top: 141px;
}

#t6_1 {
  left: 210px;
  top: 160px;
}

#t7_1 {
  left: 210px;
  top: 179px;
}

#t8_1 {
  left: 238px;
  top: 141px;
  letter-spacing: -0.1px;
  word-spacing: -0.1px;
}

#t9_1 {
  left: 238px;
  top: 160px;
  word-spacing: -0.1px;
}

#ta_1 {
  left: 238px;
  top: 179px;
  word-spacing: -0.1px;
}

#tb_1 {
  left: 343px;
  top: 242px;
  letter-spacing: -0.1px;
}

#tc_1 {
  left: 210px;
  top: 278px;
}

#td_1 {
  left: 210px;
  top: 297px;
}

#te_1 {
  left: 210px;
  top: 315px;
}

#tf_1 {
  left: 210px;
  top: 334px;
}

#tg_1 {
  left: 238px;
  top: 278px;
  word-spacing: -0.1px;
}

#th_1 {
  left: 238px;
  top: 297px;
  word-spacing: -0.1px;
}

#ti_1 {
  left: 238px;
  top: 315px;
  word-spacing: -0.2px;
}

#tj_1 {
  left: 238px;
  top: 334px;
  word-spacing: -0.1px;
}

#tk_1 {
  left: 286px;
  top: 393px;
  word-spacing: -0.1px;
}

#tl_1 {
  left: 210px;
  top: 429px;
}

#tm_1 {
  left: 210px;
  top: 448px;
}

#tn_1 {
  left: 210px;
  top: 466px;
}

#to_1 {
  left: 210px;
  top: 485px;
}

#tp_1 {
  left: 238px;
  top: 429px;
  word-spacing: -0.3px;
}

#tq_1 {
  left: 238px;
  top: 448px;
  word-spacing: -0.1px;
}

#tr_1 {
  left: 238px;
  top: 466px;
  word-spacing: -0.1px;
}

#ts_1 {
  left: 238px;
  top: 485px;
  word-spacing: -0.2px;
}

#tt_1 {
  left: 326px;
  top: 544px;
  letter-spacing: -0.1px;
}

#tu_1 {
  left: 210px;
  top: 580px;
}

#tv_1 {
  left: 210px;
  top: 599px;
}

#tw_1 {
  left: 210px;
  top: 618px;
}

#tx_1 {
  left: 238px;
  top: 618px;
}

#ty_1 {
  left: 210px;
  top: 636px;
}

#tz_1 {
  left: 238px;
  top: 636px;
}

#t10_1 {
  left: 210px;
  top: 655px;
}

#t11_1 {
  left: 238px;
  top: 580px;
  word-spacing: -0.1px;
}

#t12_1 {
  left: 238px;
  top: 599px;
  word-spacing: -0.2px;
}

#t13_1 {
  left: 238px;
  top: 655px;
  word-spacing: -0.1px;
}

#t14_1 {
  left: 264px;
  top: 716px;
  word-spacing: -0.2px;
}

#t15_1 {
  left: 210px;
  top: 752px;
}

#t16_1 {
  left: 210px;
  top: 771px;
}

#t17_1 {
  left: 210px;
  top: 789px;
}

#t18_1 {
  left: 210px;
  top: 808px;
}

#t19_1 {
  left: 238px;
  top: 752px;
  word-spacing: -0.1px;
}

#t1a_1 {
  left: 238px;
  top: 771px;
  word-spacing: -0.1px;
}

#t1b_1 {
  left: 238px;
  top: 789px;
  word-spacing: -0.2px;
}

#t1c_1 {
  left: 238px;
  top: 808px;
  word-spacing: -0.1px;
}

.s1_1 {
  FONT-SIZE: 85.4px;
  FONT-FAMILY: Arial;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  FONT-WEIGHT: bold;
}

.s2_1 {
  FONT-SIZE: 61.2px;
  FONT-FAMILY: Arial;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  FONT-WEIGHT: bold;
}

.s3_1 {
  FONT-SIZE: 61.2px;
  FONT-FAMILY: SymbolMT_1z5;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.s4_1 {
  FONT-SIZE: 61.2px;
  FONT-FAMILY: Arial;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

div {
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.button {
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid orange;
  border-radius: 20px/50px;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.button:hover {
  background: orange;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  transition: opacity 500ms;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  height: 578%;
  width: 117.5%;
}

.overlay:target {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  display: none;
}

.PopUp {
  margin: 50px auto;
  padding: 0px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 60%;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 5s ease-in-out;
}

.PopUp .close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 30px;
  transition: all 200ms;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}

.PopUp .close:hover {
  color: orange;
}

.PopUp .content {
  max-height: 117.5%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.pdf1 {
  width: 935px;
  height: 1210px;
  background-color: white;
  -moz-transform: scale(1);
  z-index: 0;
  border: none;
}

button {
  background-color: Transparent;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  outline: none;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #2D2D2D;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1;
  text-align: center;
}

.Print {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: -5px;
}

.close-message {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: black;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  line-height: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 9px;
}

.timer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 20px;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="PopUp" class="overlay">
  <div class="PopUp">
    <div class="timer" id="timer"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/87XaOWA.png">
      <p class="close-message" id="close-message"></p>
    </div>
    <a class="close" href="#">&#10005;</a>
    <div class="content" id="content">
      <div id="p1" class="p1" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; width: 885px; height: 878px;">
        <!-- Begin page background -->
        <div id="pg1Overlay" style="width:100%; height:100%; position:absolute; z-index:1; background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0); -webkit-user-select: none;"></div>
        <div id="pg1" class="pg1" style="-webkit-user-select: none;"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/vcY42CW.png" id="pdf1" class="pdf1"></img>
        </div>
        <!-- End page background -->

        <!-- Begin text definitions (Positioned/styled in CSS) -->
        <div id="t1_1" class="t s1_1">Player Selection Criteria Evaluator Cue Card</div>
        <div id="t2_1" class="t s2_1">Skating – speed, quickness, technique</div>
        <div id="t3_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
        <div id="t4_1" class="t s4_1">Forward and Backward</div>
        <div id="t5_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
        <div id="t6_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
        <div id="t7_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
        <div id="t8_1" class="t s4_1">Turn both directions</div>
        <div id="t9_1" class="t s4_1">Stop both directions</div>
        <div id="ta_1" class="t s4_1">Are they in a good position for stability and strength</div>
        <div id="tb_1" class="t s2_1">Passing – technique, control, vision</div>
        <div id="tc_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
        <div id="td_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
        <div id="te_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
        <div id="tf_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
        <div id="tg_1" class="t s4_1">Forehand and Backhand</div>
        <div id="th_1" class="t s4_1">To moving and stationary target</div>
        <div id="ti_1" class="t s4_1">Vision – do they take a look and select best option</div>
        <div id="tj_1" class="t s4_1">Advanced – board passes, chips, saucer passes</div>
        <div id="tk_1" class="t s2_1">Puck Control – technique, open ice, confined space</div>
        <div id="tl_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
        <div id="tm_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
        <div id="tn_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
        <div id="to_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
        <div id="tp_1" class="t s4_1">Open carry with speed</div>
        <div id="tq_1" class="t s4_1">Execute dekes and fakes on the 1 on 1</div>
        <div id="tr_1" class="t s4_1">Can they handle the puck in traffic and tight space</div>
        <div id="ts_1" class="t s4_1">Ability to maintain control while being stick checked</div>
        <div id="tt_1" class="t s2_1">Shooting – technique, accuracy, velocity</div>
        <div id="tu_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
        <div id="tv_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
        <div id="tw_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
        <div id="tx_1" class="t s4_1">Velocity</div>
        <div id="ty_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
        <div id="tz_1" class="t s4_1">Accuracy</div>
        <div id="t10_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
        <div id="t11_1" class="t s4_1">Forehand and backhand</div>
        <div id="t12_1" class="t s4_1">Wrist shot, snap shot, slap shot</div>
        <div id="t13_1" class="t s4_1">Shot Selection – do they select the best shot for the opportunity?</div>
        <div id="t14_1" class="t s2_1">Game Understanding – Principles of Offence and Defence</div>
        <div id="t15_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
        <div id="t16_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
        <div id="t17_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
        <div id="t18_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
        <div id="t19_1" class="t s4_1">Player understands positional play</div>
        <div id="t1a_1" class="t s4_1">Player supports the puck on the defensive and offensive side of puck</div>
        <div id="t1b_1" class="t s4_1">Player communicates with teammates</div>
        <div id="t1c_1" class="t s4_1">Player has the ability to read and react.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Print" class="Print" align="center">
      <button onclick="printDiv()"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/HcXNoMC.png" /></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: if (e.charCode === 65 || 103)  is NOT doing what you think it is

Comment: Working [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Chris_Happy/wt1gb9of/8/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it's printed, set a printed value in localStorage or a cookie, then use that value/cookie to determine what the counter is.

```
function printDiv()
{
  var content = document.getElementById('content').innerHTML;
  var win = window.open();
  win.document.write(content);
  win.print(); // JavaScript Print Function
  if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") localStorage.setItem("printed", true);
  else setCookie("printed", true, cookieExpirationDays);
  win.close(); //It will close window after Print.
  $(".close").click(function() {
    $('#PopUp').css("visibility", "hidden");
    $('#PopUp').css("opacity", 0);
  });
  $("#timer").remove();
  clearInterval(setMsg);
}

if (localStorage.getItem("printed") || getCookie("printed")) {
  counter = 0;
} else if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
  counter = 60;
  timesVisited = localStorage.getItem("timesVisited");
  // The rest of your code
}
```

Note: This is <strike>untested</strike> **tested!**

Working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Chris_Happy/wt1gb9of/13/).

Full, simplified code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.charCode === 65 || e.charCode === 103) {
      $('#PopUp').css("visibility", "visible");
      $('#PopUp').css("opacity", 1);
    }
  });

  $('#PopUp').css("visibility", "visible");
  $('#PopUp').css("opacity", 1);


  $(".close").click(function() {

    $('#PopUp').css("visibility", "hidden");
    $('#PopUp').css("opacity", 0);
  });
});
// initialization
var counter, timesVisited;
var cookieExpirationDays = 7; // don't expire cookies for a week
// test to see if localstorage/sessionStorage is available (localStorage has no expiration date)

if (localStorage.getItem("printed") || getCookie("printed")) {
  counter = 0;
} else {

 //ternary operators
 if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    timesVisited = localStorage.getItem("timesVisited");
    timesVisited = timesVisited === null ? 0 : parseInt(timesVisited) + 1;
  localStorage.setItem("timesVisited", timesVisited);
  } else {
   timesVisited = getCookie("timesVisited");
    timesVisited = timesVisited === null ? 0 : parseInt(timesVisited) + 1;
   setCookie("timesVisited", timesVisited, cookieExpirationDays);
  }
  switch(timesVisited) {
    case 0:
      counter = 60;
    break;
  
   case 1:
    case 2:
    case 3:
    case 4:
      counter = 45;
    break;
    
   case 5:
    case 6:
    case 7:
    case 8:
    case 9:
      counter = 30;
    break;
    break;
    
   case 10:
    case 11:
    case 12:
    case 13:
    case 14:
      counter = 30;
    break;
    
    default:
      counter = 5;
    break;
    
 }

}

var setMsg = setInterval(function() {
  counter--;
  if (counter >= 60 && counter >= 70) {
    $("#close-message").html("1:" + (counter - 60));
  } else if (counter >= 60 && counter < 70) {
    $("#close-message").html("1:0" + (counter - 60));
  } else if (counter >= 10) {
    $("#close-message").html("0:" + counter);
  } else if (counter > 0) {
    $("#close-message").html("0:0" + counter);
  } else {
    $(".close").click(function() {
      $('#PopUp').css("visibility", "hidden");
      $('#PopUp').css("opacity", 0);
    });
    $("#timer").remove();
    clearInterval(setMsg);
  }
}, 1000);

function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
    var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}

function printDiv() {
  var content = $('#content').html();
  var head = $("head").html();
  var win = window.open();
  $(win.document.body).html(content);
  $(win.document.head).html(head);
  win.print(); // JavaScript Print Function
  if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") localStorage.setItem("printed", true);
  else setCookie("printed", true, cookieExpirationDays);
  win.close(); //It will close window after Print.
  $(".close").click(function() {
    $('#PopUp').css("visibility", "hidden");
    $('#PopUp').css("opacity", 0);
  });
  $("#timer").remove();
  clearInterval(setMsg);
}
```

```css
.t {
  -webkit-transform-origin: top left;
  -moz-transform-origin: top left;
  -o-transform-origin: top left;
  -ms-transform-origin: top left;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.25);
  -moz-transform: scale(0.25);
  -o-transform: scale(0.25);
  -ms-transform: scale(0.25);
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  white-space: pre;
  overflow: visible;
}

#t1_1 {
  left: 256px;
  top: 35px;
  letter-spacing: 0.1px;
}

#t2_1 {
  left: 334px;
  top: 87px;
  word-spacing: -0.1px;
}

#t3_1 {
  left: 210px;
  top: 123px;
}

#t4_1 {
  left: 238px;
  top: 123px;
  word-spacing: -0.3px;
}

#t5_1 {
  left: 210px;
  top: 141px;
}

#t6_1 {
  left: 210px;
  top: 160px;
}

#t7_1 {
  left: 210px;
  top: 179px;
}

#t8_1 {
  left: 238px;
  top: 141px;
  letter-spacing: -0.1px;
  word-spacing: -0.1px;
}

#t9_1 {
  left: 238px;
  top: 160px;
  word-spacing: -0.1px;
}

#ta_1 {
  left: 238px;
  top: 179px;
  word-spacing: -0.1px;
}

#tb_1 {
  left: 343px;
  top: 242px;
  letter-spacing: -0.1px;
}

#tc_1 {
  left: 210px;
  top: 278px;
}

#td_1 {
  left: 210px;
  top: 297px;
}

#te_1 {
  left: 210px;
  top: 315px;
}

#tf_1 {
  left: 210px;
  top: 334px;
}

#tg_1 {
  left: 238px;
  top: 278px;
  word-spacing: -0.1px;
}

#th_1 {
  left: 238px;
  top: 297px;
  word-spacing: -0.1px;
}

#ti_1 {
  left: 238px;
  top: 315px;
  word-spacing: -0.2px;
}

#tj_1 {
  left: 238px;
  top: 334px;
  word-spacing: -0.1px;
}

#tk_1 {
  left: 286px;
  top: 393px;
  word-spacing: -0.1px;
}

#tl_1 {
  left: 210px;
  top: 429px;
}

#tm_1 {
  left: 210px;
  top: 448px;
}

#tn_1 {
  left: 210px;
  top: 466px;
}

#to_1 {
  left: 210px;
  top: 485px;
}

#tp_1 {
  left: 238px;
  top: 429px;
  word-spacing: -0.3px;
}

#tq_1 {
  left: 238px;
  top: 448px;
  word-spacing: -0.1px;
}

#tr_1 {
  left: 238px;
  top: 466px;
  word-spacing: -0.1px;
}

#ts_1 {
  left: 238px;
  top: 485px;
  word-spacing: -0.2px;
}

#tt_1 {
  left: 326px;
  top: 544px;
  letter-spacing: -0.1px;
}

#tu_1 {
  left: 210px;
  top: 580px;
}

#tv_1 {
  left: 210px;
  top: 599px;
}

#tw_1 {
  left: 210px;
  top: 618px;
}

#tx_1 {
  left: 238px;
  top: 618px;
}

#ty_1 {
  left: 210px;
  top: 636px;
}

#tz_1 {
  left: 238px;
  top: 636px;
}

#t10_1 {
  left: 210px;
  top: 655px;
}

#t11_1 {
  left: 238px;
  top: 580px;
  word-spacing: -0.1px;
}

#t12_1 {
  left: 238px;
  top: 599px;
  word-spacing: -0.2px;
}

#t13_1 {
  left: 238px;
  top: 655px;
  word-spacing: -0.1px;
}

#t14_1 {
  left: 264px;
  top: 716px;
  word-spacing: -0.2px;
}

#t15_1 {
  left: 210px;
  top: 752px;
}

#t16_1 {
  left: 210px;
  top: 771px;
}

#t17_1 {
  left: 210px;
  top: 789px;
}

#t18_1 {
  left: 210px;
  top: 808px;
}

#t19_1 {
  left: 238px;
  top: 752px;
  word-spacing: -0.1px;
}

#t1a_1 {
  left: 238px;
  top: 771px;
  word-spacing: -0.1px;
}

#t1b_1 {
  left: 238px;
  top: 789px;
  word-spacing: -0.2px;
}

#t1c_1 {
  left: 238px;
  top: 808px;
  word-spacing: -0.1px;
}

.s1_1 {
  FONT-SIZE: 85.4px;
  FONT-FAMILY: Arial;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  FONT-WEIGHT: bold;
}

.s2_1 {
  FONT-SIZE: 61.2px;
  FONT-FAMILY: Arial;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  FONT-WEIGHT: bold;
}

.s3_1 {
  FONT-SIZE: 61.2px;
  FONT-FAMILY: SymbolMT_1z5;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.s4_1 {
  FONT-SIZE: 61.2px;
  FONT-FAMILY: Arial;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

div {
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.button {
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid orange;
  border-radius: 20px/50px;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.button:hover {
  background: orange;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  transition: opacity 500ms;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  height: 578%;
  width: 117.5%;
}

.overlay:target {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  display: none;
}

.PopUp {
  margin: 50px auto;
  padding: 0px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 60%;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 5s ease-in-out;
}

.PopUp .close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 30px;
  transition: all 200ms;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}

.PopUp .close:hover {
  color: orange;
}

.PopUp .content {
  max-height: 117.5%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.pdf1 {
  width: 935px;
  height: 1210px;
  background-color: white;
  -moz-transform: scale(1);
  z-index: 0;
  border: none;
}

button {
  background-color: Transparent;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  outline: none;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #2D2D2D;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1;
  text-align: center;
}

.Print {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: -5px;
}

.close-message {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: black;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  line-height: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 9px;
}

.timer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 20px;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="PopUp" class="overlay">
  <div class="PopUp">
    <div class="timer" id="timer"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/87XaOWA.png">
      <p class="close-message" id="close-message"></p>
    </div>

    <a class="close" href="#">&#10005;</a>
    <div class="content" id="content">
      <div id="p1" class="p1" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; width: 885px; height: 878px;">

        <!-- Begin page background -->
        <div id="pg1Overlay" style="width:100%; height:100%; position:absolute; z-index:1; background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0); -webkit-user-select: none;"></div>
        <div id="pg1" class="pg1" style="-webkit-user-select: none;"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/vcY42CW.png" id="pdf1" class="pdf1" /></div>
        <!-- End page background -->


        <!-- Begin text definitions (Positioned/styled in CSS) -->
        <div id="t1_1" class="t s1_1">Player Selection Criteria Evaluator Cue Card</div>
        <div id="t2_1" class="t s2_1">Skating – speed, quickness, technique</div>
        <div id="t3_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
        <div id="t4_1" class="t s4_1">Forward and Backward</div>
        <div id="t5_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
        <div id="t6_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
        <div id="t7_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
        <div id="t8_1" class="t s4_1">Turn both directions</div>
        <div id="t9_1" class="t s4_1">Stop both directions</div>
        <div id="ta_1" class="t s4_1">Are they in a good position for stability and strength</div>
        <div id="tb_1" class="t s2_1">Passing – technique, control, vision</div>
        <div id="tc_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
        <div id="td_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
        <div id="te_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
        <div id="tf_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
        <div id="tg_1" class="t s4_1">Forehand and Backhand</div>
        <div id="th_1" class="t s4_1">To moving and stationary target</div>
        <div id="ti_1" class="t s4_1">Vision – do they take a look and select best option</div>
        <div id="tj_1" class="t s4_1">Advanced – board passes, chips, saucer passes</div>
        <div id="tk_1" class="t s2_1">Puck Control – technique, open ice, confined space</div>
        <div id="tl_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
        <div id="tm_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
        <div id="tn_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
        <div id="to_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
        <div id="tp_1" class="t s4_1">Open carry with speed</div>
        <div id="tq_1" class="t s4_1">Execute dekes and fakes on the 1 on 1</div>
        <div id="tr_1" class="t s4_1">Can they handle the puck in traffic and tight space</div>
        <div id="ts_1" class="t s4_1">Ability to maintain control while being stick checked</div>
        <div id="tt_1" class="t s2_1">Shooting – technique, accuracy, velocity</div>
        <div id="tu_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
        <div id="tv_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
        <div id="tw_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
        <div id="tx_1" class="t s4_1">Velocity</div>
        <div id="ty_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
        <div id="tz_1" class="t s4_1">Accuracy</div>
        <div id="t10_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
        <div id="t11_1" class="t s4_1">Forehand and backhand</div>
        <div id="t12_1" class="t s4_1">Wrist shot, snap shot, slap shot</div>
        <div id="t13_1" class="t s4_1">Shot Selection – do they select the best shot for the opportunity?</div>
        <div id="t14_1" class="t s2_1">Game Understanding – Principles of Offence and Defence</div>
        <div id="t15_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
        <div id="t16_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
        <div id="t17_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
        <div id="t18_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
        <div id="t19_1" class="t s4_1">Player understands positional play</div>
        <div id="t1a_1" class="t s4_1">Player supports the puck on the defensive and offensive side of puck</div>
        <div id="t1b_1" class="t s4_1">Player communicates with teammates</div>
        <div id="t1c_1" class="t s4_1">Player has the ability to read and react.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Print" class="Print" align="center">
      <button onclick="printDiv()"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/HcXNoMC.png" /></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

<strike>I'm not very experienced with cookies or localstorage, but it seems that you want to clear the cookie or the value in localstorage. To clear the localStorage, you can use: `localStorage.removeItem("timesVisited");`. To clear the cookie, you can use: `setCookie("timesVisited","",-1);`</strike>

Note: I don't if you're using the function, but don't you need to declare your `setCookie` function? [See here.](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)

Comment: If I reset `timesVisited` back to `0` then the timer would be 60 seconds. Not even close to being removed. I still want `timesVisited` to work it just gets overruled if the 'Print' button has been clicked. When the 'Print' button has been clicked I want it to either set the `counter` variable to `0` or remove the timer all together using the code I provided in my question.

Comment: Gotcha, then yeah, you have to create a new cookie/localstorage as @epascarello stated, and use that as an if statement.

Comment: I was waiting for the laundry, so I simplified the code for you :) Any questions, just ask!

Answer (score 4):

`if (e.charCode === 65 || 103)` is NOT doing what you think it is. It is not if it is either of those.

It is saying "if e.charCode is equal to 65 or 103 is truthy than do this".

You need to use e.charCode === on both sides

```
if (e.charCode === 65 || e.charCode === 103)
```

`e.charCode` is also non standard. You should probably be using `e.which`

```js
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    
    if (e.charCode === 65 || 103) {
       $("#yours").html(e.charCode)
    } else {
       $("#yours").html("nope")
    }


    if (e.charCode === 65 || e.charCode === 103) {
       $("#mine").html(e.charCode)
    } else {
       $("#mine").html("nope")
    }

    
    
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Yours:  <span id="yours"></span></div>
<div>Mine:  <span id="mine"></span></div>
```

And to answer your question. So add a different localStorage key that it was printed. Add an if statement around the code to see if it was. If it was, than do not initialize the timer or add the event handler.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if (localStorage.wasPrinted) return;  //add cookie check also
  .... rest of code ....
})
```

Comment: Seems to be working just fine. Anyways was it really necessary to answer my question with something completely unrelated?

Comment: There is no way that is working.... It will always be going into the `if`... Sorry for helping you with a bug. lol

Comment: Copy my code into an HTML file. Then close the popup. Then press the letter 'g' or 'G'. The popup should reappear which is what that bit of code is supposed to do. If you were to remove that bit of code it wouldn't work. It definitely works because I just tried removing it and it did nothing.

Comment: I added a DEMO to show you what is happening. Click on the page and type random keys.... It should say NOPE so anything other than the codes you provided.

Comment: Well thanks for fixing the bug but aren't answers only to directly or indirectly answer the question? Comments are for bugs right?

Comment: LOL... Sorry for taking time out of my day to help you. So for your code what is hard to set a value in localstrorage to say it was printed. Than add an if that it was... You also have a typo in the code after the clearInterval where there is an `s`

Comment: I'm not complaining about you fixing the bug, I'm actually glad that particular bug didn't slip through the cracks.